# Android: is it possible to change the description of an Android app once submitted and in production on Android or Amazon Market?

Tags: android, google-play, amazon-appstore

I am going to submit my app on Android and Amazon market.

For these both markets, once the app validated and in production, is it possible to:

1. modify the app description ?
2. add languages for the app description ?
3. change the promo text and promo image (Android Market) ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android Market you can change anything anytime you want. I'd imagine it's the same for the Amazon App Store, although they are more strict about what is allowed so it may not be instantaneous.

Answer (score 1):

Everything other than the application package can be changed for a published application in android Market. Of course, unless you want to update the application with a new version. I don't know much about the Amazon AppStore, though.